Is it possible that cohesive energy of a material is positive but the phonon dispersion curve have negative frequencies?
The calculated cohesive energy for the material is positive which indicates the material is stable, however when I checked dynamical stability using the finite element method it has negative frequencies. Could anyone please describe whether this material is stable or not?

The word "stable" has more than one meaning. It's ambiguous to talk about whether a material is stable without a context

A positive cohesive energy indicates that it is more stable than a free gas of the element, not that it is stable.  I would think that it should be difficult to find an optimized structure with a negative cohesive energy, as that would indicate it should form a monatomic gas.
If you check phonon stability and see large imaginary modes, it is not stable.  If you see small imaginary modes, it is possibly just DFT convergence issues.  Also keep in mind that there may be finite temperature effects and it is possible to see imaginary modes on a material that is known to be stable and exist (but likely not at 0 K).
